# he php- $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] truncating the output

Tags: php

I am using the following code to get user's IP and get it sent to my email address (I'm using a third party email API):

```
<?php
$ip1 = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
$ip2 = $_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR']
$ip3 = $_SERVER['HTTP_FORWARDED'];
$ua = $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'];

$to = 'abc@xyz.com';
$sub = 'test';
$msg = "$ip1, $ip2 and $ip3 on $ua  \n ...other texts...";

$post = "key=blah&to=$to&sub=$sub&msg=$msg";
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'http://example.com');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURL_POSTFIELDS, $post);
curl_setopt($ch, CURL_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
$mailres = curl_exec ($ch);

?>
```

The API just retrieves the $_POST data and uses mail() to send email.

But when I execute the code I get the mail with the user's IP stored in $ip1 only. For eg, if user's IP is 1.1.1.1 then I get only:

> 1.1.1.1,

No user agent and other texts are sent.What could be the problem?

Comment: Should that be a comma after `$to` in the mail arguments? Its hard to tell as you do not define what `$to` and `$sub` are.

Comment: Have you tried to output `var_dump($_SERVER)` and see what's inside of it? You can save it to your email by using `ob_start(); var_dump($_SERVER); $dump = ob_get_clean()`. Be aware that this might contain information you don't want to give to everyone, so if you post the content here, **please verify that there's no personal information**!

Comment: @thatidiotguy ir was a typo, sorry

Comment: @h2ooooooo the problem is  that the mail text is getting truncated after writing the value in $ip1

Comment: one more thing it was working well on my shared server, i have this problem on a VPS

Comment: @Ashish That wouldn't happen based on your code though. Are you sending the email as HTML? Does the user agent contain any `<` or `>` characters? Check the *source* of your email instead of what your client displays. Or are you asking why `HTTP_FORWARDED` and `HTTP_X_FORWARDED_TO` are empty? Then it's because these are usually only populated if you use a proxy.

Comment: @h2ooooooo i am saying that my mail should contain IP address(s), UA of the user along with other thing that I have specified. but the mail i get only has the value stored in $ip1, nothing else. maybe $_SERVER is causing problem as i am also gettting a notice related to HTTP_FORWARDED undefined index whn i send the mail

Comment: Let's start with the basic. The user has *one* IP you can read. The one of their interface making the request (or the routers interface if over the internet). The reason your server vars are empty is because you're not using a proxy. The correct way to check an IP is using *either* `REMOTE_ADDR` *or* `HTTP_FORWARDED` *or* `HTTP_X_FORWARDED_TO`. Not all of them. If you output the contents in your browser or look at your mail *source* code, you might figure out why it's not being displayed. Is it not in the mail at all? Is it there but not being shown? If it's being stripped why is it?

Comment: Does it work simply to output the mail as a string before sending it and looking at it there? Does that also not work? The more and more you can figure out about *where* a bug happens, the quicker you can get to fixing it. If your PHP echo does not work, it's a problem with the string. If your email simply does not display it, it's a problem with HTML encoding. If your email does not have it at all, but PHP prints the string, it's probably an error with your mail setup on your server.

Comment: @h2ooooooo I think I got it, when i display mail text in browser then it displays everything. btw i am using a third party api using curl to send mail. is it possible that it is causing the problem?

Comment: It might be - could you post the exact code you use to send the email with? Your example uses the `mail` function, and not `curl`. Perhaps you do something else with your string before then? If you *do* post your code, make sure you minify it to the least bit of code and remove any information. Let us know what API you use, what you send to it, what it sees etc.

Comment: @h2ooooooo okay i'm editing the post

Comment: @h2ooooooo its done, please check it now

Comment: Alright, so it might be due to several things. First of all, you're not escaping your content. Imagine if `$sub` is "Reasons & Non-reasons". Your API would see that as "sub=Reasons[space]" and "& Non-reasons". I suggest you use an array and use [`http_build_query`](http://www.php.net/http_build_query): `$post = http_build_query(array('key' => 'blah', 'to' => $to, 'sub' => $sub, 'msg' => $msg))`. Secondly, I would use `htmlentities($msg)` instead of `$msg` in case you're sending the email as HTML. Thirdly, you should implement it so it only uses one IP. [Here's a function](http://goo.gl/4stcI4)

Comment: @h2ooooooo I got what was causing the problem. Used urlencode($msg) and the problem solved. but i am also sending the output of getallheaders() but when I get the mail it says `User's headers  are: Array`. When I echo getallheaders() in browser then it displays the headers but when I send the mail it displays "Array". It is not an API problem cuz I tried using my own mail()  and even then it displays 'Array' in mail instead of headers. Any idea why is it so and how to solve this?

Comment: Use `print_r($array, true)` to get a printed version of an array. When you use `echo $array` you simply get "Array" because PHP doesn't see a logical reason why you'd input an array in the middle of a string unless it was an accident.

Comment: @Ashish You're very welcome. Glad you got it working, and welcome to StackOverflow! :-)

Answer (score 0):

try this way first, just to be sure that you debug something real:

```
$text = '';
if (isset($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'])) {
    $text .= $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'].', ';
} else {
    $text .= 'NO _SERVER[\'REMOTE_ADDR\'] HERE, ';
}

if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'])) {
    $text .= $_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'].', ';
} else {
    $text .= 'NO _SERVER[\'HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR\'] HERE, ';
}

if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_FORWARDED'])) {
    $text .= $_SERVER['HTTP_FORWARDED'].', ';
} else {
    $text .= 'NO _SERVER[\'HTTP_FORWARDED\'] HERE, ';
}
if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'])) {
    $text .= ' on '.$_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'].', ';
} else {
    $text .= 'NO _SERVER[\'HTTP_USER_AGENT\'] HERE, ';
}
$text .= "\n ...other texts...";

mail ($to, $sub, $text  );
```

but with curl it should be:

```
$post = array("key"=>'blah',
'to'=>$to,
'sub'=>$sub,
'msg'=>$msg);
```

and

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURL_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($post));
```

Comment: oooops, you've changed the `mail` to `curl` ??

Comment: You're suddenly JSON encoding everything? What makes you think the API uses JSON?

Comment: CURLOPT_POST + CURL_POSTFIELDS 90% is json. and by the way, isn't it weird that first it was mail? and now it is curl? and topic title is `he php- $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] truncating the output` ? yes, this question is very strange, but I just trying to help

Comment: It *very* much depends on the API. Only if the endpoint is expecting a JSON POST payload rather than POST parameters can you JSON encode it.